# Need a regex ninja's help with replacing a YouTube string

Tags: wygwam, low, low-replace

I'm looking for some help with replacing YouTube embed codes with something that can be used with AMP pages https://www.ampproject.org/

Example, we would like replace this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="439" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" width="780"></iframe>
```

with this:

```
<amp-youtube width="480" height="270" layout=responsive data-videoid="xxxxxxxxxxx"></amp-youtube>
```

Unfortunately, we can't simply replace the `iframe` tag with `amp-youtube` because we have other non-YouTube iframes floating around our site. To make things even more complicated, the YouTube embed codes live in our main content area as a WYGWAM field. Obviously, we'd like to also retain the video ID, illustrated above as 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

I've gotten pretty close with using [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) but my head can't wrap around regex. Here is the template code for our main content:

```
{exp:low_replace regex="yes" find='youtube_example' replace='amp_example' multiple="yes"}
    {exp:ce_img:bulk max_width="780" bucket="site" hide_relative_path="yes" attributes='layout="responsive"'}
        {content}
    {/exp:ce_img:bulk}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy, chief. I can't deal with going through the Low Replace docs right now, so you'll have to apply the right parameters, but here you go:

Matching pattern:

```
<(iframe)(.*)(src=\"https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed)
```

Replace pattern:

```
<amp-iframe$2$3
```

This will match groups `iframe`, anything inbetween `iframe` and the beginning of the `src` tag, and the then the beginning of the `src` tag.

I give you a demo (when you click on the link, make sure to switch to `preg_replace`, not `preg_match`):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hjP

That should do it, but test it as it might need tweaking.

Comment: Whoa!!! Thank you thank you thank you!!! I had to tweak it a bit, but it's working now.

Comment: Oop, yeah I probably didn't read your exact required answer correctly. Derp! But glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you jrothafer for the answer. For those curious, here is the fix. It probably needs some cleaning up, but it's working.

Matching pattern

```
<(iframe)(.*)(src=\"https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed)\/(.{11})" width="780"><\/iframe>
```

Replace pattern

```
<amp-youtube width="480" height="270" layout="responsive" data-videoid="$4"></amp-youtube>
```